# Redirecting page based on country

Tags: javascript, web-services

I have created a web service which will return the Country Code, Now what I want is adding this web service to a JavaScript on my webconfig file, so that it will be redirected based on the Country Code. I know it's simple but I am very new to this and didn't find any answers.

Again I need a JS which will redirect my page to a different link based on the result of web service so I need to know how to call this WS in JS and redirect it.

Comment: This question can be closed as Too Broad.

Answer (score 0):

Look up `window.location.replace` on google...

What I would do is a small jscript webservice call in the header that gets the country code and then writes the redirect info from above into the page itself.  You would have to test, but this is where I would start myself.

here's the idea:
- call the webservice to get the country code
- setup a switch statement javascript method that will account for the different country codes and use the `window.location.replace('newUrl')` method to redirect the page to the proper url.

Without knowing your exact code, service calls, return values, etc. there's no way to write it all otu for you; however, if you do 5 minutes of research you'll find your answer using the general idea from above.